# Q promises queue with idleness callback

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I made a background queue of tasks using Q like this:

```
function enq (step)
  var f = function() {
    var d = Q.defer();
    step(d);
    return d.promise;
  }
  enq_head = enq_head.then(f);
  handleBusiness(); //see later
}
```

where enq_head is a global promse. The step parameter is the task and it fulfills the promise.

Now I'd like a callback to be called when this queue changes between busy and idle. The best I could come up with was:

```
function handleBusiness() {
  if (!businessCallback) {
    return 0;
  }
  var busynow = enq_head.isPending();
  if (busynow) {
    businessPromise = enq_head.then(handleBusiness);
  }
  if (busynow != businessReported) {
    businessReported = busynow;
    if (businessCallback) {
      businessCallback(businessReported); 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but it looks a mess and the performance is horrible because if it's usually busy I need two .thens every time a new task gets added.

Is there something built in that would do this better?

Comment: Have you tested performance, was it really "horrible"?

Comment: Enabling the callback slowed things down by a factor of 2 or 3. In the meantime I just dumped promises and use setTimeout without any callback. I could recreate the callback using a counter of pending jobs.